# Is there any way to make a PC obtain the Forsaker Prestige class at 2nd level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, prestige-class

The forsaker requires 3 feats:

- Great Fortitude
- Lightning Reflexes
- Iron Will

Is there a way to obtain all those 3 feats at level 1 so I can become a forsaker at level 2?

If not, what is the minimal level a PC can obtain the forsaker class?

Comment: This is a good example of why a prestige class should include "hard" limits such as a minimum BAB or class features, in addition to general feats that are more "flavorful" than limiting.  It's also an example of newer mechanics (ie flaws giving bonus feats) may give unintended synergies (ie prestige class being available much earlier than intended).

Answer (score 10):

To get all 3 feats at level 1, use some combination of the following:

- Human or Strongheart Halfling - 1 extra feat
- Dwarf domain - Great Fortitude feat
- Drow domain - Lightning Reflexes feat
- A quick stay in the Otyugh Hole - Iron Will feat
- Taking 1 or 2 flaws - 1 or 2 extra feats

Comment: Just an aside: The Otyugh Hole usually isn't an option for a I-just-made-this-dude-right-here-at-the-table level 1 character. The DM is supposed to strip 3,000 gp of treasure out of an adventure's treasure in exchange for a stay in the Otyugh Hole. No adventures from which to strip treasure yet? No benefits of the Hole.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I know, but I'd feel pretty weird if I didn't mention it. Maybe a higher-level adventurer is retraining to get into forsaker?

Comment: There are quite a few ways — many of them as or more shady than saying *But it's in my background that I got thrown into the Hole!* — to get free feats. That is, I'm not sure the answer's helped by listing only one implausible method while not listing more… and that's not what the question's *really* about. I recommend the Hole's omission and sticking instead to commonplace options, but I welcome your disagreement.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't think he needs to remove it, but I feel it should be segregated, for clarity.

Answer (score 6):

Flaws described in "Unearthed Arcana" book allows players to chose up to two flaws - for each of them, PC gains an extra feat. So at 1st level, you can choose three (AFAIR even four if your character is Human) feats.